Repeated variable in type derivation tree
I want to write the type derivation for $x + y \times x$. This has $x, y : \text{int}$, and I would have thought this would be written (assuming rules for $+, \times$, and variables)
$$
  \frac{\Gamma \vdash x : \text{int} \quad \displaystyle \frac{\Gamma \vdash y : \text{int} \quad \Gamma \vdash x : \text{int}}{\Gamma \vdash y \times x : \text{int}}}{\Gamma \vdash x + y \times x : \text{int}}
$$
How can I write this without repeating $\Gamma \vdash x : \text{int}$?

Why do you want to do that? I don't think there's an established notational convention for sharing subderivations, but you could always make up your own.

@NaïmFavier To avoid duplication. My use case has two and three duplications of two variables, and it feels wrong when they're talking about the same variable.

"It's not possible/standard" is a useful answer
